# How to receive the html of a webpage using the dotnet tcpclient

Tags: c#, .net-core, tcpclient

I want to be able to get the html from a page given an address, I would like to know how I should configure the TcpClient to be able to make valid get requests. I cannot use the HTTPClient.

```
 using var tcpClient = new TcpClient();

        var hostname = "google.com";
        tcpClient.Connect(hostname, 80);

        using NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        networkStream.ReadTimeout = 2000;

        var message = @"GET / HTTP/1.1
                        Accept: text/html, charset=utf-8
                        Connection: close
                        " + "\r\n\r\n";

        Console.WriteLine(message);

        using var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        networkStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

I have tried this, however I receive a 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: Aren't you missing the Host? Per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.23 *A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request
   messages .*  and further on: *All
   Internet-based HTTP/1.1 servers MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request)
   status code to any HTTP/1.1 request message which lacks a Host header
   field.* so the google.com server response is within specification, your `message` isn't.

Comment: I included it as www.google.com,but the result was the same

Comment: But you don't connect to www.google.com, your hostname says "google.com".

Comment: Why not use `HttpClient` out of curiosity?

Comment: Too easy and convenient for a healthy academic environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned by @rene you need Host header field ... and your header should not have spaces or tabs before it

```cs
var hostname = "google.com";
tcpClient.Connect(hostname, 80);
//...
var message = @$"GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Host: {hostname}
" + "\r\n\r\n";
```

this will return status code `301 Moved Permanently` to [www.googel.com](http://www.googel.com)

```cs
var hostname = "www.google.com";
tcpClient.Connect(hostname, 80);
//...
var message = @$"GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Host: {hostname}
" + "\r\n\r\n";
```

this will make the request success with status code `200 OK`